# chef env command line utility is only showing output for --help instead of prompting for license acceptance

Tags: command-line, zsh, command-line-arguments, local, chef-workstation

When I try to [accept the chef license from the command line](https://docs.chef.io/chef_license_accept/#chef-workstation), as part of my chef workstation setup, I just see the output for the --help flag

```
user in ~  > chef env --chef-license accept
Prints environment variables used by Chef Workstation

Usage:
  chef env [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for env

Global Flags:
      --chef-license ACCEPTANCE   Accept product license, where ACCEPTANCE is one of 'accept', 'accept-no-persist', or 'accept-silent'
  -c, --config CONFIG_FILE_PATH   Read configuration from CONFIG_FILE_PATH
  -d, --debug                     Enable debug output when available
  -v, --version                   Show Chef Workstation version information
```

I have no idea why this could be happening. I'm using a zsh shell on mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you also get the help, when you do a `chef env -v`? What do you see when you do a `chef -v`? What do you get when you do a `type -a chef`?

Comment: @user1934428 yes `chef env -v` also gives me the help output. `chef -v` however behaves as it should and shows the versions of all the chef utilities that ship with the chef workstation installation. `type -a chef` prints the following in a single output on two separate lines `chef is /opt/chef-workstation/bin/chef`
`chef is /usr/local/bin/chef`

Comment: I don't know _chef_ at all, but from your description, I would try next a `chef --chef-license accept`.

Comment: All that does is show the `chef --help` output unfortunately

Comment: I have no idea, but looking at [this](https://docs.chef.io/chef_license_accept/) page, it seems to suggest the command `chef-server-ctl reconfigure --chef-license=accept`. The page also proposes other ways to accept the license.